# What's the difference between time-dependent flow (isotopy) and time-independent flow?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields

Regarding the fact that both time-independent and time-dependent vector fields correspond with family of diffeomorphisms, i.e. $\{\phi_t | t\in\Re, \phi_t: M\to M\}$, what's the difference between these two families, i.e, time-independent and time-dependent flows (isotopy)?

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific. What is it exactly that you're trying to find out? Are you asking about the definition? Some properties? Something else? At the moment, it is not clear what you are after.

Comment: Consider $\{X_t | t\in\Re\}$ as a time-dependent vector field. If we correspond to each $X_t$ a family of diffeomorphisms as its flow, it seems to me that a family of families of diffeomorphisms "should" correspond to the time-dependent vector field.But it is not so. For example, da Silva in his book Lectures on Symplectic Geometry defines isotopy (or time-dependent flows) via the family of diffeomorphisms, not the family of families of diffeomorphisms. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Amin, it seems like your comment should be the question.  The original question is somewhat vague.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\varphi_t:M\to M,\;t\in \mathbb{R}$, be a smooth family of diffeomorphisms. "Smooth" means here that the corresponding map $$\varphi:M\times\mathbb{R}\to M,\quad(p,t)\mapsto\varphi_t(p),$$ is smooth. For every $t$, define the vector field $X_t$ by $$X_t(p)=\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=t}\varphi_s\left(\varphi_t^{-1}(p)\right).$$Then the family $(\varphi_t)$ is generated by the time-dependent vector field $X_t$, in the sense that for every $q$ and $t$ we have $$\frac{d}{dt}\varphi_t(q)=X_t(\varphi_t(q)).$$In other words, the family $(\varphi_t)$ is the solution to the ODE given by the time-dependent vector field $X_t$. Now, in very specific cases $X_t$ may turn out to be independent of $t$, but it does not change anything, essentially.

Answer (score 11):

I'll use Amitai Yuval's notation.

Notice that if $X_t=X$ does not depend on $t$, then the equation
$$\frac{d}{dt}\varphi_t(p)=X(\varphi_t(p))$$

means that $\varphi$ is the flow of $X$. In particular, $\varphi_t\circ\varphi_s=\varphi_{t+s}$ for all $t,s\in\mathbb{R}$ (which is a natural property of the flow).

Conversely, assume $\varphi_t\circ\varphi_s=\varphi_{t+s}$ $\forall t,s\in\mathbb{R}$. In particular $\varphi_t^{-1}=\varphi_{-t}$. By definition of $X_t$ we have
\begin{align*}
X_t(p)&=\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=t}\varphi_s(\varphi_t^{-1}(p))\\
&=\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=t}\varphi_{s-t}(p)\\
&=\left.\frac{d}{du}\right|_{u=0}\varphi_u(p),\,\,\,\text{where }u=s-t.
\end{align*}

This shows that $X_t$ does not depend on $t$. So we have just proved that

> $X_t$ is independent of $t\Leftrightarrow$ $\varphi_t\circ\varphi_s=\varphi_{t+s}$ for all $t,s\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is a very good answer. I think in the last line you meant : "$X_t$ is independent of $t$ if and only if $\varphi_t\circ \varphi_s=\varphi_{t+s}$" so I edited it. Please let me know if I misinterpreted what you meant.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis, yes, that's what I meant. Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Would you say a few words how $\frac{d}{dt}\varphi(p)=X(\varphi_t(p))$ implies the group property? I assume we need to show $\varphi(t,\varphi_s(q))=\varphi(t+s,q)$?

Comment: @chikurin, you can fix $s$ and $q$ and define the curves $\alpha(t):=\varphi(t,\varphi_{s}(q))$ and $\beta(t):=\varphi(t+s,q)$. Both $\alpha,\beta$ are integral curves of $X$ starting at $\varphi_s(q)$, so they must be the same curve by uniqueness of integral curves.

Comment: For a detailed discussion, check out Lee's _Introduction to Manifolds_, chapter 12.